# Worklight app updates every time after opening app and calling adapter call

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I am using **Worklight 6.2 Consumer Edition** and has done following configuration formy App:

**application-descriptor.xml configuration**

```
<iphone applicationId="MyApp" bundleId="ex.am.ple"  version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>
```

**authenticationConfig.xml configuration**
**

```
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
```

**

I publish an update for my app --> open my app --> call adapter procedure --> app ask for update --> app gets updated --> close the app --> open my app --> call adapter procedure --> app ask for update.

Everytime when I close my app and calls adapter procedure the above scenario is happening. Is it like device is not keeping the updated resources or there is a problem in my configuration?

Comment: 1. Is this happening in the development environment in eclipse, or in a production environment in an external server? if it is in an external server, provide full steps - from building the .wlapp to deploying it. what are you doing? 2. why do you need to call an adapter to get the update? are you not using wl.client.connect in your app?

Comment: WL.Client.connect() call is there in the app in main.js file. But app is not getting updated at the application startup, rather it is showing update dialog box after user login (through adapter procedure call) is successful. I am testing in QA Environment have build everything through ANT script. I have deployed .war through ant script and then deployed adapter and application .wlapp files through worklight console.

Comment: Can u share the logs?

Comment: IOS Version of the device?

Comment: Check device logs to confirm if file is getting downloaded ? May be download is getting interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 scenarios that would trigger repeated Direct Update requests:

1. The web resources installed on the device differ than those that are deployed to the Worklight Server or vice versa; you need to make sure to always re-deploy the updated .wlapp if you are making changes (and installing the app from Eclipse to the device, but not update the server; this is a recipe for repeated Direct Update requests).
2. You have several servers in your topology, but they are not synced and so whenever the app connects (if you have a load balancer), it jumps between the servers, where one is updated and the other is not updated. The .wlapp should be deployed to all servers, but more importantly, the server should be set-up as a farm of servers.

Comment: I am using only one server right now, point second is not at all valid in my case. Regarding point one, after taking the update how can server web resources and device web resource be out of sync?

Comment: Test again but without using the Ant script. Build from eclipse. Does it still happen?